# Max between lines and columns if given value is lower - c++

Tags: c++, algorithm

1st time asking and i am pretty noob in c++ so please be gentle. Thanks!

I have the given problem: if the value is lets say 3 and i have a matrix of 2 lines and 2 columns, i want my program to do the max between the lines and columns which have elements lower than the given value (3).

Here is the what i've tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm> 
#include <numeric>

using namespace std;


int main() {

    int e, markLine[0],markRow[0];

    int ary[2][2] = { {2,3},
                      {3,2} };
    e=3;

    for (int i =0; i < markRow.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j< markLine.size(); j++)
        if( ary[i][j] < e ) {
            markLine[i]=1;
            markRow[j]=1;
        }
        std::cout << (std::max(std::accumulate(markLine),std::accumulate(markRow)));
    }

}
```

Comment: `markLine[0]` and `markRow[0]` are arrays with no elements in them. I'm guessing you wanted `markLine[2]` and `markRow[2]`?

Comment: oh yes, thank you very much. and i want this function to return how many lines and how many columns exists that have elements lower than 3. and to do the max between them. can you help me with that?

Comment: You said you want the rows / columns which have elements lower than 3. Does that mean rows / columns that have at least one element lower than 3 OR rows / columns that have all elements lower than 3?

Comment: at least one element lower than 3

Comment: @Roxi I'd urgently recommend you should use `std::array` and `std::vector` instead of raw arrays when using the c++ language.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i dont know how that works..this is the only method i've learned in school :(

Comment: @Roxi _"this is the only method i've learned in school"_ They're well known to teach the stuff in a bad manner.  [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) and [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) were specifically designed to make your life easier when dealing with arrays. You may inform yourself using the linked reference documentations here.

Comment: @Roxi Take a look at the version with `std::array` https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/APkZ7T

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in C++ are not objects and therefore they don't have any method like size() defined for them.

So, markRow.size() is wrong.

In the variable declaration statement, the integer arrays markLine[ ] and markRow[ ] need to be assigned a size. So, writing markLine[0] and markRow[0] just means that arrays of size 0 are being created. That is wrong.

Assign a size to markLine[ ] and markRow[ ].

To assign markLine[ ] and markRow[ ] with zero values just use for loops, to initialize them separately or initialize them directly(as they are pretty small arrays)

```
for(i=0;i<2;i++)
{
 markRow[i]=0;
 markLine[i]=0;
}
//or
//markRow[ ]={0,0};
//markLine[ ]={0,0};
```

accumulate function does not work like as written, but it takes three parameters. The starting location, the ending location and a third variable which it adds with partial sum calculated.

`accumulate(first,last,sum);`

You don't need to use std as you are already using namespace std.

The "using namespace std;" statement automatically adds std:: wherever in the program needed.

Finally the question written was not very clear and therefore, I can't figure out the motive or expected output of the program.

But if corrected at the required places, as directed in this answer, the program will run successfully.